# Popcorn.js loop in video

Tags: video, html5-video, popcornjs

I'm working on an interactive video using Popcorn.js but I'm quite new to JavaScript. I'm trying to loop a specific part in the video. I was trying an if statement where when a current Time is achieved the current Time will be set back. Unfortunately this doesn't work.

```
function loop() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    if (video.currentTime = 82)
    { 
        (video.currentTime = 77)
    }
}
```

Do any of you guys have a suggestion/solution?

Comment: Are you just using the `baseplayer`?

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't have anything in front of me to verify this, but you should be able to do this by attaching to the `timeupdate` event. You should be able to do that like this:

```
document.getElementById('video').timeupdate = function () {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    if (video.currentTime == 82) {
        video.currentTime = 77
    }
};
```

and you can do that where ever it's relevant in your overall application.